# Storing reference to child function in parent

Tags: reactjs

I have an interesting use case for storing references to a function that belongs to a child component. As an aside, I'm using the React's new context API to pass data to deeply nested children components.

I have found a number of other answers that address similar problems, but they dont quite match my use case. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487740/call-methods-on-react-children-components).

This is the high level problem:

1. A `Provider` component called `<Parent />` contains logic and state that is passed to all the `<Child />` components which are the `Consumers`.
2. `Child` components receive a `verify` prop that is essentially a validator function of sorts for that particular `Child`. Each call to `verify` produces a `verificationResult` based on incoming state changes from the the `Parent`.
3. Importantly, all the other `Child` components must be notified or be aware of the result of each `verificationResult` produced by its siblings.
4. To make things extra interesting, I'd prefer not to store the so called `verificationResult` of each child in the parent's state if I dont have to since it is essentially derived state and can be computed in `Parent` `render()`.

**Solution 1:**

store `verificationResult` of each child in `Parent`. This could be done by waiting for the relevant value to change in each `Child`'s `componentDidUpdate()`like so:

```
// Child.js
...
componentDidUpdate(pp) {
  const { hash, value, verify, setVerificationResult } = this.props

  // this check is a little more involved but 
  // the next line captures the gist of it. 
  if(pp.value[pp.hash] !== value[hash]) {
    setVerificationResult(hash, verify(value[hash], value))
  }
}
...

// Parent.js
...
setVerificationResult(hash, result) {
 this.setState(({ verificationResults }) => ({
    ...verificationResults, [hash]: result
 })) 
}
...
```

**Note:**

- `this.props.value` and `this.props.setVerificationResult` is received from the `Parent` which is a context `Provider`, while
- `this.props.hash` and `this.props.verify` are passed to the `Child` component directly.

`this.props.hash` grabs the portion of `value` which this particular `Child` needs to know about.

```
// MyComponent.js

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <Child 
      hash="someHash"
      verify={(value, allValues) => {
        return value === 42 && allValues["anotherHash"] === 42
      }}
      render={({ verificationResults }) => (
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(verificationResults["someHash"], null, ' ')}</pre>
      )}
    /> 
   ...
)
```

Solution 1 conforms to unidirectional data flow principle that react encourages. However I have 2 issues with this solution. Firstly, I'm having to store what is essentially state that can be derived. Secondly, calling `setVerificationResult()` will cause an unwanted re-render. Not to mention the additional logic in `componentDidUpdate`

**Solution 2**

The next options looks something like this. Note that I've tried show only the important bits:

```
// Child.js
...
componentDidMount() {
  const { register } = this.props
  register(this.verify)
}

verify(values) {
  const { hash, verify } = this.props
  return { [hash]: verify(values[hash], values) }
}
...

// Parent.js
constructor(props)
  super(props)
  this.tests = [] 
  this.state = { 
    value: null, 
    // other initial state
  }
  ...
}

register(verifyFunc) {
  this.tests.push(verifyFunc)
}

render() {
  const { value } = this.sate
  let result = {}
  this.tests.forEach(test => result = { ...result, ...test(value) })
  return (
    <Provider 
      value={{
        ...this.state,
        verificationResults: result,
        register: this.register,
        // other things...
     }}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Notice that in the second solution I'm not storing any additional state since its just calculated on the fly. However I am storing references to a function on a child component.

Can anyone tell me why **NOT** to use solution 2? Any alternative suggestions on how to make this work?

Additional notes:

- Why not pass the verify function to the Parent directly? I could, but it wouldn't make for a very clean API.
- You can assume that I'm performing the necessary clean up on unmount, etc.
- The problem is more complex than shown here - there are in fact deeply nested Consumers that communicate with a "local" Provider which "splits" values and logic until they reach so called leaf Components, while a "Master" Provider is used as the root node containing all component state and logic in the hierarchy of components.

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by "all the other Child components must be notified or be aware of the result of each verificationResult produced by its siblings".
In a sense of, why do they need to be notified? And is there a way to use a some kind of service to notify them? (some kind of a flux type architecture)

Comment: On your second question of why not to use solution number 2: in all honestly you can, however it is not recommended and not the react way. By that I mean, that react was created with a certain mindset, where all changes to the application are DATA driven. If everything is data driven, a parent component should not be able to independently make a child component do something, what it should do is change data and tell the child to see if any of those data changes applies to them.

Comment: This is in order to make everything organized, all the child component logic and logic of when things happen are in the child component.

Comment: 1. I want this to be pure react. As few dependencies as possible - that goes double for a state management library.
2. Perhaps notify is the wrong word. The problem at its core is that a prop on a child needs to make changes to state in a parent, and that bit of state needs to be available in all consumers. However when you think of validation (in this case I simply call it verification)  validation is a product of the current state of some value or values. It need not be stored in state (this forms part of the reason for my preference for solution 2).

Comment: You can implement flux yourself, however it might be an overkill if you just use it because of this. Ultimately it's a matter of judgement that only you can make, because you have all the most information on the kind of project you are building.