# Why is this function in the redux-form source code wrapped by another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

My question relates to an implementation detail in the [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) source code. Simply, I'd like some insight into the reasoning behind and thinking that went into the following snippet of code that can be found in `src/createField.js` [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/23b1fbd219bd1d81b55e2271c3352379c70007c4/src/createField.js#L44) and [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/23b1fbd219bd1d81b55e2271c3352379c70007c4/src/createField.js#L65).

```
this.context._reduxForm.register(
     newName,
     'Field',
     () => nextProps.validate,
     () => nextProps.warn
)
```

My question is **not** about how or where these functions are being used, but specifically *why* are these functions are wrapped in the manner that they are. For instance why not simply use:

```
this.context._reduxForm.register(
  newName,
  'Field',
  nextProps.validate,
  nextProps.warn
)
```

My guess is that it has to do with storing direct references to these functions in a parent component. My interest in this is related to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50603526/storing-reference-to-child-function-in-parent) I've asked on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` depends on how a function is called. Separating a function call from the object will break the connection to that object in `this`.

```js
var nextProps = {
    validate: function () { console.log("This is ", this); }
};

function callFunction(callback) {
    callback();
}

console.log("======");
console.log("Preserve this");
callFunction(() => nextProps.validate());
console.log("======");
console.log("Don't preserve this");
callFunction(nextProps.validate);
```

Comment: Interesting observation -  perhaps I'm not entirely convinced by your example: the function is wrapped like so `() => nextProps.validate`  not `() => nextProps.validate()` so when the value is [unwrapped](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/23b1fbd219bd1d81b55e2271c3352379c70007c4/src/createReduxForm.js#L658) and finally [used](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/23b1fbd219bd1d81b55e2271c3352379c70007c4/src/generateValidator.js#L18) the lexical scope of `this` as it was is not kept. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Note that `validate` can be a function or an array of functions or undefined if no value is passed in.

Comment: @StuartBourhill —`() => nextProps.validate` creates a function which **mentions** `nextProps.validate` but doesn't call it and effectively does nothing at all.